# Clear out Redactor WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

We have a redactor editor which we populate from the database but once we have submitted the data back we need to clear the textarea.

We have tried various combinations but are unable to clear it out.

```
jQuery("#redactor").redactor('set', '');
```

AND

```
jQuery("#redactor").val("");
```

Comment: It looks like you could `.redactor('selectionAll')` then `.redactor('selectionRemove')`. Other options might be `insertText` or `insertHtml`.

Comment: _once we have submitted the data back_.....Can you post it in your question above?

Comment: The code you provide is `jQuery("#redactor").redactor('set', '');
` is actually working on the redactor demo page. http://imperavi.com/redactor Clears the visual view and the textarea too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#redactor").redactor('code.set', '');
```

updated version

Comment: Please just don't post code only answers.  please explain what the code is going

Comment: It sets the code in redactor to an empty string ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With Redactor version 3, I had to use below code in order to clear redactor textareas:

```
$('.redactor-in').html('');
```

Note: This clears all redactor textareas in the current page, one need to change the class name `.redactor-in` inside the jQuery DOM selector if they want to clear specific textareas and leave some.

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with the `DOM` you can just clear the innerHTML

```
$('.redactor_editor').html('');
```

Source: [How to clear input or HTML or text on the redactor wysiwyg editor?](http://joonhachu.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/how-to-clear-input-or-html-or-text-on.html)

There's also some more documentation on http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/

```
$('#redactor').redactor('insertHtml', 'your code');
```

Comment: It's generally not a great idea to edit WYSIWIG editor content outside of the editor. If possible, it is best to do it with functions provided by the editor, or remove and re-add.

Comment: We tried your suggestions - insertHtml works great to insert the data from the database into the editor, but using $('#redactor').html(''); doesn't clear it, neither does $('#redactor').val('');

Comment: Hi Jared 
We have text in the textarea and the user submits this and we save it to the database. We then need to clear the text from the textarea, otherwise it remains and if the user re-opens the text is added again to the text area. All we are needing to do it blank the text area once we have saved the data

Comment: This worked for me: `$( '.redactor_editor' ).empty();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code sample for RedactorX

```
$('.rx-editor p').html("")
```